# How to copy files if size nonzero in shell?

Tags: shell, cp

I have some files that I want to copy from one directory to another with a shell script but I only want to copy the ones that have something in them. Right now this is what I have but it won't check to make sure that the files aren't empty. `cp -f /some/folder/* /another/folder/`
 Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Is it for Linux or Unix or both?

Comment: Its going to be on an Ubuntu vm so Linux.

Comment: You can get filesize by: FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FILENAME")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `find` command for this:

```
find . -type f -size +0 -print0 | xargs -0 -I % cp % /dest/
```

`-size +0` will get files with size greater than zero.